# Boolean vector from regex

Tags: c++, regex

I've got trouble getting the regex in C++ working.
Eventually, I'd like to build a boolean vector from the matched groups ("**IT**O**IS**BFAMPM" -> "**11**0**11**000000").
To build the vector, I need to get the start and length of each group.

The pattern works well on [regexr.com](http://regexr.com/3d9pe) and I get all the goups. But my code returns an empty result set.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <regex>

using namespace std;

string board = "ITOISBFAMPM"
"ACQUARTERDC"
"TWENTYFIVEX"
"HALFBTENFTO"
"PASTERUNINE"
"ONESIXTHREE"
"FOURFIVETWO"
"EIGHTELEVEN"
"SEVENTWELVE"
"TENSEOCLOCK"
"1234";

string pattern = ".*(IT).*(IS).*(HALF).*(PAST).*(TWELVE).*(123).*";
// string pattern = "(PAST)";


int main()
{
    regex rgx(pattern);
    smatch result;
    regex_search(board, result, rgx);

    cout << board << endl;
    cout << pattern << endl;

    cout << result.size();
    for(size_t i=0; i<result.size(); ++i)
    {
        cout << result[i] << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What compiler are you using? What version of it? There are still many compilers being used that lack full C++11 support, especially when it comes to the regular expression functionality.

Comment: Your code seems to [work for me](http://rextester.com/GDT28322), exactly as shown.

Comment: I'm running it on https://c9.io/ with the C++ (simple) runner. So far, I couldn't figure out more details.

Comment: I just ran the `c++ --version` command. It's running on `c++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.1) 4.8.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As indicated by Igor Tandetnik, the code works as is. The problem lies in the interpreter.